# How to Generate single tag on visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, jsx, emmet

I am learning React. How can I generate single tag on visual studio code or what is the shortcut for single tag.

[image: Click here for image]

Comment: Type a `/` before the `>`

Answer (score 0):

well you can use "auto close tag" extension on your visual code. Just write your tag and user '/'. Your tag will closed automatically.[Click for you image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er64p.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking how it is done in the gif you posted, they are formatting the file when saving it using [prettier](https://prettier.io/)

How can you do it?

**Install prettier**

```sh
npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier
```

**Configure VSC to format on save**

1. Open preferences -> settings
2. Go to Text Editor -> Formatting
3. Check the `Format on Save` checkbox

Comment: I am using same but that's not happening